# What is the name for a graph showing the estimated electoral vote share based on polling over time?

Tags: united-states, terminology, electoral-college, polling

I'm looking for the right words to use to find a trend graph that shows how the US electoral vote count would look over time. "If the election were held today" kind of thing. This isn't about past elections. It'd be tracking the run up to the presidential election.

A dated trend graph would, over time, weight polls of individuals by the electoral college votes they impact so it wouldn't simply be predicting the popular vote. For example, [The Economist has such a graph here](https://projects.economist.com/us-2020-forecast/president):

[image]

All I can find is [maps](http://frontloading.blogspot.com/2020/08/the-electoral-college-map-81020.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed:+fhq+(Frontloading+HQ)&m=1) based on current data and "national polls" that disregard the electoral college.

I'm sure what I'm looking for exists. I just can't seem to figure out the right name. What is it called?